# Path outside the build context error when building container in Github Actions

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I have a .Net multi-project solution that I'm containerizing and I'm trying to automate the build with Github Actions.

This is a simplified overview of my file structure:

```
repo/
├── Solution.sln
└── src/
    ├── Core/
    │   └── Project.Domain/
    │       └── Project.Domain.csproj
    └── Presentation/
        └── Project.API/
            ├── Project.API.csproj
            └── Dockerfile
```

The API project depends on the Domain project (among others in reality) and it won't be the only containerized project in the solution, so there will be multiple Dockerfiles.

This is the beginning of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env

WORKDIR /App

COPY ../../../ ./

# The reset of the build steps...
```

When I build the container locally (Git Bash on Windows with Docker Desktop) using the following command, it passes:

```
$ pwd
/path/to/repo
$ docker build -f ./src/Presentation/Project.API/Dockerfile .
```

I have a github workflow to automate that, this is the workflow file:

```
name: Dev Deployment
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy API
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - name: Build
        run: |
          docker build -f ./src/Presentation/Project.API/Dockerfile .
```

I get the following error:

```
Step 3/11 : COPY ../../../ ./
COPY failed: forbidden path outside the build context: ../../../ ()
```

How do I fix this and why does it work on Windows but not in the Action?

Comment: Set the context such that the file you want to `COPY` does not reside outside the context.

Comment: I'm already doing that, in the build command I'm specifying the context as `.` while in the root directory of the repo, so this makes the entire repo the context, the copied files are all within it.

Comment: The host-paths specified in a `COPY`-directive are always relative to the context directory. So the paths are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the execution does currently reside in `/repo` (i.e. `pwd` is `/repo`), the `COPY`-directive in the `Dockerfile` is wrong. The host-path of the `COPY` is always relative to the context, not the `Dockerfile` (just like the contaier-path is relative to the `WORKDIR`). Hence

```
COPY ../../../ ./
```

should be

```
COPY . .
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, what I didn't realize is that the COPY path is relative to the context and not the Dockerfile itself. Still weird that it worked locally. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `working-directory` keyword, you can specify the working directory of where to run the command. As example:

```
      - name: Build
        working-directory: src/Presentation/Project.API
        run: |
          docker build -f ./Dockerfile .
```

or just change directory before running the command

```
      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd src/Presentation/Project.API
          docker build -f ./Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Now would this change the fact that the path is outside the context directory?